# Count number of string occurrence java

Tags: java, if-statement, iterator

I have an

```
Iterator<Text> values
```

where every text holds period/type pairs.

it looks like this

morning sms
morning voice
morning sms
morning sms
morning voice
day sms
day voice
evening sms
evening voice
evening sms
evening voice
evening sms
evening voice
evening sms
evening voice
night sms
night voice
night sms
night voice

Is there a way to count how many times a pair appears without a lot of if else blocks?

the result should be

3 morning sms
2 morning voice
1 day sms
1 day voice
3 evening sms
3 evening voice
2 night voice
2 night voice

Comment: Yes there are many ways. What have you tried so far and what's the issue in it?

Comment: Just put them in a `Map<Text, Integer>` and count, assuming that those `Text` properly implement `hashCode` and `equals`.

Comment: use a `Map<Text,Integer>` with each text as its keys and a counter as it's value. On each iteration, get the counter by the key and increment it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use a `HashMap<Text,Integer>` to keep track of every distinct period/type pairs where `Text` is the `key` and the `Integer` is the `value` which is the frequency.

```
HashMap<Text,Integer> m = new HashMap<Text,Integer>();
//Populate the HashMap
while(values.hasNext()) 
{
  Text element = values.next();
  if(m.get(element) == null)
  {
   m.put(element , 1);
  }       
  else m.put(element , m.get(element) + 1);   
}

//Display the frequencies
for (Map.Entry<Text, Integer> entry : m.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println(entry.getValue() + "/" + entry.getKey().period  );
}
```

I have assumed that `Text` is class that has public field named `period` containing string like `morning sms`

Comment: In yout example **itr** is **values**?

Comment: @EugeneCuz Yes, i have just edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use Streams.collect for that:

```
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();

    values.add("morning");
    values.add("evening");
    values.add("morning");

    // Function.identity() means p->p, since example collection is very simple
    // If your objects are more than strings, you'll need to map them: p -> p.getName(), for example
    Map<String, Long> collect =
            values.stream().collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()));

    System.out.println(collect);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
HashMap<String, Integer> maps = new HashMap<>();
      while(itr.hasNext()) {
          Object element = itr.next();
          Integer i = maps.get(element.toString());
          if(i == null) {
              maps.put(element.toString(), 1);
          }
          else {
              maps.put(element.toString(), ++i);
          }
       }

      //See result
      for(Entry<String, Integer> e : maps.entrySet()) {
          System.out.println(e.toString());  
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method for example

```
public static int countStringOccurrences(String text, String pattern) {

int count = 0;
int i = 0;
// Keep calling indexOf for the pattern.
while ((i = text.indexOf(pattern, i)) != -1) {
    // Advance starting index.
    i += pattern.length();
    // Increment count.
    count++;
}
return count;
}
```

Read about it in:

https://www.dotnetperls.com/string-occurrence-java